# TYPO3 10.4 - how do I determine which FE-Group may assign a BE-Group?

Tags: php, typo3, access-control

i am using TYPO3 10.4. I have a BE-Group which rules the access to a specific page, where a my FE-Users. I got it to enable the access to this page and enable that the BE-group is allowed to create new FE-Users, but i don't understand how to rule, which FE-Group the BE-User can give to a FE-User?
I have nothing found in the "Backend users" module sadly.

I hope something out here can help me :)

Best regards

Comment: I don't know if I have understood your question correctly...
When you edit a BE Group, you'll have a tab called "Access Lists" where you can set which Database Tables the BE Group can view and modify and which fields of each table.

If you want your BE Group to access and modifiy FE Groups and FE Users, you must check
- Tables (listing) > "Website Usergroup" and "Website User"
-  Tables (modify) > "Website Usergroup" and "Website User"

The single fields of these tables are listed in the section "Allowed excludefields"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Thx for your reply! I know how to allow to create new fe users, but i am wondering how can i set for a BE-Group which FE-Groups he can give to FE-Users he created. Currently there are no BE-Groups shown unter "Editing Fe-Users" -> "Groups".

Comment: When you edit a "FE user" you can assign to it one or more "FE group".
You can't assign a "BE Group" to a "FE user" as they're completely distinct entities.
Or I am understanding it wrong what you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you have the abbility to determine which fe-groups a backenduser can assign to a frontend user. You could try to create two folders for the fe-groups. And then give the backenduser only acces to the folder with the fe-groups he is allowed to assign. Don't know if this works. I did not test. But i think this is the only way to achive what you want.